# Powershell remove text after first instance of special character

Tags: parsing, powershell

This is the value that I have to parse.

```
8.2.4.151.65; HBAAPI(I) v1.3; 3-29-02
```

I need to remove everything after and including the first instance of `;`

So I need my ending result to be `8.2.4.151.65`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$s = '8.2.4.151.65; HBAAPI(I) v1.3; 3-29-02'
$s.Substring(0, $s.IndexOf(';'))
```

Answer (score 27):

Split on the `;` and take the first string.

```
'8.2.4.151.65; HBAAPI(I) v1.3; 3-29-02'.split(';')[0]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer fails if it doesn't contain ;

Answer (score 4):

Using a regex with a lazy match:

```
'8.2.4.151.65; HBAAPI(I) v1.3; 3-29-02' -replace '(.+?);.+','$1'

8.2.4.151.65
```

The ? makes the match 'lazy', so it stop at the first ;

Comment: Worked great on Posh v2.