# Parse a property of a connection string

Tags: powershell, azure, servicebus

I have a string like the one below and I need to parse it out using PowerShell. I only want to keep the string up to the "EntityPath" and take out everything after the entity path:

```
Endpoint=sb://abcdefg.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=listenkey_1137;SharedAccessKey=W2c26OiBwae9f/vgPcJWgtD709oTTJu1VlB8i4OkqUc=;EntityPath=listen_1137
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell remove text after first instance of special character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044226/powershell-remove-text-after-first-instance-of-special-character)

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
$mystring="Endpoint=sb://abcdefg.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=listenkey_1137;SharedAccessKey=W2c26OiBwae9f/vgPcJWgtD709oTTJu1VlB8i4OkqUc=;EntityPath=listen_1137"
$NameValue=$mystring -replace ";", "`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData
$NameValue.EntityPath
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution!  I've been doing Powershell for some time now but haven't seen a reason to try the `ConvertFrom-StringData` method before.  Thanks for an simple elegant way to get the value!

Answer (score 0):

```
$testStr = "Endpoint=sb://abcdefg.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=listenkey_1137;SharedAccessKey=W2c26OiBwae9f/vgPcJWgtD709oTTJu1VlB8i4OkqUc=;EntityPath=listen_1137"

$parts = $testStr -split "EntityPath"

Write-Host $parts[0]
```

This might work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what you are asking now but it's a second question I suppose. I'll attempt to understand your question as it is somewhat broken English.

```
function Invoke-MyWork($testStr)
{
     $parts = $testStr -split "EntityPath"
     $parts[0]
}
$originalValue = "Endpoint=sb://abcdefg.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=listenkey_1137;SharedAccessKey=W2c26OiBwae9f/vgPcJWgtD709oTTJu1VlB8i4OkqUc=;EntityPath=listen_1137"

$upToEntityPath = Invoke-MyWork $originalValue


Write-Host "UpToEntityPath: $($upToEntityPath)"
Write-Host "OriginalValue: $($originalValue)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using *regex*.

```
$ep = "Endpoint=sb://abcdefg.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=listenkey_1137;SharedAccessKey=W2c26OiBwae9f/vgPcJWgtD709oTTJu1VlB8i4OkqUc=;EntityPath=listen_1137"
[regex]::Match($ep, 'EntityPath=([^;|\s]+)').Groups[1].Value # output: listen_1137
[regex]::Match($ep, '(EntityPath=[^;|\s]+)').Groups[1].Value # output: EntityPath=listen_1137
```